# How to Save the Output of a script that loops a python script using subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, subprocess

How to save the output of a python script that loops a python script

```
from datetime import datetime
import faker
import json
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
import subprocess
import json
import os
from pprint import pprint
import subprocess
import sys


for i in range(20):
    subprocess.call(['python','curlloop1.py'])
```

this code loops my python script that generates random json files. i need to save the outut everytime i loop it..

curl.py code that generates random json and save the output to a json file

```
import faker
import json
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
import subprocess
import json
import os
#subprocess.call([""])
from pprint import pprint

ids= ('5cda','7f36')

fake = Faker('en_US')

for ind in ids:
    cont = []
    #Overall dictionary with first and user_ids
    dct = {}
    for idx in range(20):


        sms =  {
            "id":"AB-Iasd",
            "body": fake.sentence(),
            "reae": fake.ean(),
            "ashe": fake.ean(),
            "id2": fake.ean(),
            "user_id": ind,
            "pid": fake.sentence()
        }
        cont.append(sms)
    #Use a dictionary to save cont list to first key, and ind to user_ids key
    dct['messages'] = cont
    dct['user_id'] = ind
    #print(dct)
    f_name = '{}.json'.format(ind)
    with open(f_name, 'w') as fp:
        #Save the dictionary
        json.dump(dct, fp, indent=4)
        print('saved {}'.format(f_name))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping the outer file `curlloop1.py` in another file, you can just add a overall for loop which runs 20 times, collects all dictionaries in a list, and then save that list as a dictionary in a single file

```
import faker
import json
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
import subprocess
import json
import os
#subprocess.call([""])
from pprint import pprint

ids= ('5cda','7f36')

fake = Faker('en_US')

msg_list = []

#Overall loop to run inner loop 20 times
for _ in range(20):
    #Loop to generate messages
    for ind in ids:
        cont = []
        #Overall dictionary with first and user_ids
        dct = {}
        for idx in range(20):


            sms =  {
                "id":"AB-Iasd",
                "body": fake.sentence(),
                "reae": fake.ean(),
                "ashe": fake.ean(),
                "id2": fake.ean(),
                "user_id": ind,
                "pid": fake.sentence()
            }
            cont.append(sms)
        #Use a dictionary to save cont list to first key, and ind to user_ids key
        dct['messages'] = cont
        dct['user_id'] = ind
        msg_list.append(dct)


#Saving overall data to a single dictionary and to a file
data = {"data":msg_list}

f_name = 'data.json'
with open(f_name, 'w') as fp:
    #Save the dictionary
    json.dump(data, fp, indent=4)
    print('saved {}'.format(f_name))
```

The `data.json` will look like

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "messages": [
                {
                    "id": "AB-Iasd",
                    "body": "Up west accept third success bad.",
                    "reae": "0181541986524",
                    "ashe": "1490107025812",
                    "id2": "4087146706078",
                    "user_id": "5cda",
                    "pid": "Color wish method population affect."
                },
                {
                    "id": "AB-Iasd",
                    "body": "Human expect news son room recognize beautiful.",
                    "reae": "9417635708941",
                    "ashe": "0920108608482",
                    "id2": "8218562976929",
.....
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56144385/how-to-save-the-output-json-fileof-a-subprocess-that-is-in-a-loop    pl check this.

Comment: Sure thing, I added an answer to the question, please check @thoris !