# how to save the output (json file)of a subprocess that is in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, subprocess

this code send generates a random json file of user ids provided and btw 
 range is also given..

so this code outputs 50 jsons for each user.

```
import faker
import json
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
import subprocess
import json
import os
#subprocess.call([""])
from pprint import pprint

ids= ('5cda','6cda')

fake = Faker('en_US')

for ind in ids:
    cont = []
    #Overall dictionary with first and user_ids
    dct = {}
    for idx in range(50):

        sms =  {
            "id":"AB-asfgw",
            "body": fake.text(),
            "mime": fake.ean(),
            "hashed": fake.ean(),
            "pid": fake.ean(),
            "user_id": ind,
            "text": fake.sentence()
        }
        cont.append(sms)

    dct['messages'] = cont
    dct['user_id'] = ind
    #print(dct)
    f_name = '{}.json'.format(ind)
    with open(f_name, 'w') as fp:
        #Save the dictionary
        json.dump(dct, fp, indent=4)
        print('saved {}'.format(f_name))    

auth = "authorization: token 1324"
file = "5cda.json"
fd=open("5cda.json")
json_content = fd.read()
fd.close()


subprocess.run(["grpcurl", "-plaintext","-H", auth,"-d",json_content,"-format","json","100.20.20.1:5000","api.Service/Method"])
```

this loop.py code loops the first code 20 times

```
from datetime import datetime
import faker
import json
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
import subprocess
import json
import os
#subprocess.call([""])
from pprint import pprint
import subprocess
import sys



for i in range(20):
    subprocess.call(['python','grploop1.py'])
```

i need to save the output of loop.py code for each loop. and store that json. example : we are looping the first code for 20 times in loop.py so ineed the output stored should be like 5cda1.json ........  5cda20.json and  6cda1.json.....   6cda20.json

here we are giving two user ids `ids= ('5cda','6cda')` so output would be total 40 json files.

Comment: Why would you use subprocess to call one piece of Python code from another?

Comment: cz grpcurl cant take more than 33676 chars in terminal. so i m trying to loop them in another code and store the outputs

Comment: I don't know what `cz grpcurl` is. What does the number of chars in a terminal have to do with anything?

Comment: `subprocess.run(["grpcurl", "-plaintext","-H", auth,"-d",json_content,"-format","json","100.20.20.1:5000","api.Service/Method"])`   I am reading a json file and loading it into  in grpcurl because i couldnt find a way how to load a file directly in  grpcurl.   So the json file would be loaded into terminal and my json file is huge and terminals limit for taking the input is 33676 charecters. and it is giving me the error of content too long. So I am trying to loop the program in another program.

Comment: But `grpcurl` is specifically for running from the command line. If you want to call a gRPC endpoint from code, why don't you use a Python gRPC library?

Comment: i m new and i couldn't understand how to invoke the data using grpc py library and docs are also very  less,  So have invoked data using grpc ui and grpc curl as thier docs is straight forward in command line. If you know hove to invoke data using py library share some articles it would be helpfull. I just need to invoke the data from my code to grpc. protos are already configured. I just need the invoking part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to bring the file saving logic inside the `for ind in ids:` loops, and use the index in the overall loop to save the file with different names.

```
import faker
import json
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
import subprocess
import json
import os
#subprocess.call([""])
from pprint import pprint

ids= ('5cda','7f36')

fake = Faker('en_US')

msg_list = []

#Overall loop to run inner loop 20 times
for i in range(20):
    #Loop to generate messages
    for ind in ids:
        cont = []
        #Overall dictionary with first and user_ids
        dct = {}
        for idx in range(20):


            sms =  {
                "id":"AB-Iasd",
                "body": fake.sentence(),
                "reae": fake.ean(),
                "ashe": fake.ean(),
                "id2": fake.ean(),
                "user_id": ind,
                "pid": fake.sentence()
            }
            cont.append(sms)
        #Use a dictionary to save cont list to first key, and ind to user_ids key
        dct['messages'] = cont
        dct['user_id'] = ind
        msg_list.append(dct)

        #Append the index to the file here, and save the file
        f_name = '{}{}.json'.format(ind,i+1)
        with open(f_name, 'w') as fp:
            # Save the dictionary
            json.dump(dct, fp, indent=4)
            print('saved {}'.format(f_name))
```

You will get 40 files as per your requirements, with unique content in all files.

Comment: sry for that confused and added , Have removed and added in question

Comment: added pl check.

Comment: can the same logic can be applied in subprocess that stores the output to a file everytime it loops

Comment: `i need to save the output of loop.py code for each loop` i have mentioned in q the same. And being new i cant post another question , They are restricting me to post another one

Comment: i have confirured in grpcui and its working for huge requesrs, But in grpcurl i need to explore that and  it is returning error,  Leave the grpcurl part i need  loop.py output to save after each loop.  or shall i drop a another question about the same.

Comment: `subprocess.run(["grpcurl", "-plaintext","-H", auth,"-d",json_content,"-format","json","100.20.20.1:5000","api.Service/Method"])` I am reading a json file and loading it into in grpcurl because i couldnt find a way how to load a file directly in grpcurl. So the json file would be loaded into terminal and my json file is huge and terminals limit for taking the input is 33676 charecters. and it is giving me the error of content too long. So I am trying to loop the program in another program...      so i need the saving part to be done in loop.py so that i can limit the first program

Comment: your code saves the file in the first code itselt and i dont need that cz it will exceeds the terminal limit. I need to save the file in second program while the first code is looping in second code each time for 20 times

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56147033/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-python-file-that-has-been-looped-in-another-python-f     pl check into this

Comment: added a new q pl look into that @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: that q is completely on python not at all on grpcurl.

Comment: Sure I will look into it in some time and also allow others to look into the question!

Answer (score 0):

You can save the output of called python file to a file if you write the J-son into STDOUT and in loop.py redirect the STDOUT to a file.
In you "generator" file: (Of course, you should remove other prints if you don't want to get invalid J-son file.)

```
...
dct['messages'] = cont
dct['user_id'] = ind
print(dct)
...
```

I your loop.py file:

```
subprocess.call(["ardbuf", "-oL", "python","grploop1.py", ">", test_folder/tmp_file.json])
```

Comment: where should i create the test_folder

Comment: With "tempfile" official module. Link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Comment: sorry couldnt understand

Comment: why should we use temp file ?